# split value to reuse with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my code I have something like:

```
color: {{item.color}}
```

Which works fine for single items, however at times I also can get a value like:

white|black

How can I split these values to be individual items?

I've used:

```
 ng-bind-html="renderProperty
```

however it doesn't really give me the format I'd like.

Comment: What does the item object look like? and what is your desired format?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little please? What do you wish to be individual values? The `white|black`? Do you mean that you receive that as input and you want it to become two variables that are `white` and `black`?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Add a filter object to your app so you can call

`{{ item.color | split }}`

```
angular.module('myFilters', []).filter('split', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input.split('|')[0];
  };
});
```